# How to read a file and delete a string from a particular line

Tags: ruby

I have the following files:

---

**ids_to_remove.txt**

```
ID  File_Name   Row Name

id\a_po87y  GMT_dealer  auto_dev
id\ruio66   dao_wells   auto_dev
id\rzd766   123_Smart_option    cia_read
...
...
etc
```

**GMT_dealer-details.txt**

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal

[groups]

auto_dev = id\a_po87y, id\rt7890, id\sdfs09, id\rzdo9k
qa_check = id\op9iu, id\guijm0, id\a_po87y
AD_read = id\a_po87y
```

**dao_wells-details.txt**

```
#Content may be structured and packaged into modules to facilitate delivering, extending, and upgrading the Content

[groups]

AD_read = id\a_po87y
auto_dev = id\guijm0, id\oikju8, id\ruio66
CSI = id\kiopl, id\ruio66, id\o9i8u7
```

---

In `ids_to_remove.txt`, there are close to 500 entries, and items in a row are tab separated. In other files, groups values are space separated.

The value for `File_Name` represents a folder or file at `E:/my_files/*-details.txt`, where `*` is the `File_Name` value like `GMT_dealer`, `dao_wells`, or `123_Smart_option`.

For each row, I want to delete any occurrence of the `ID` value in row with the row id `Row Name` in the file represented by `File_Name`. For example, I want to delete the string `id\a_po87y` from row with id `auto_dev` in file `GMT_dealer`. `id\a_po87y` should be removed only from the group `auto_dev`, and the same id present in groups `qa_check` and `AD_read` should be left as is. Likewise it has to be carried out on all files under `E:/my_files`.

I wrote the code below:

```
file_dir = 'E:/my_files'

file = File.open("E:/ids_to_remove.txt", "r")
contents = file.each_line.map { |line| line.split("\t") }.transpose
id, file_name, group  = contents


id.each do |ids|
  puts "For id: #{ids}"
  file_name.each do |name| 
   value = File.open("#{file_dir}/#{name}-details.txt")
   text = File.read(value)

   text.each_line do |el|
    group.each do |gr|
     if el.match(/#{gr}/) then 
      print "group row #{gr}\n"
      replace = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(ids)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(ids)}/, '' ).gsub /,\s*$/, ''
     end
     group.shift
    end 
   end
   file_name.shift
  end
end  
id.shift
```

It doesn't do what I need. Looking for any suggestions.

For debugging added few puts and the output I got

```
For ID: id\a_po87y
group row auto_dev

group row auto_dev

For ID: id\ruio66
For ID: id\rzd766
```

Comment: sawa - Thanks for the edit, I'm new to this forum and getting adjusted. Could you please help me with the issue.Thanks

Comment: "It doesn't do what I need" - what does it do instead?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev , thanks for looking into it. It doesn't replace the string in the target files. No errors too. Not sure where should I make the change.

Comment: What's up with `group.shift` and `file_name.shift`? What do you need them for?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev , I'm trying to remove the first element of all the 3 arrays - **id** , **group** and **file_name** once the 1st id or string got deleted in the first file in the corresponding row. i may be wrong with the logic. Looking for your expertise suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do something like this:

```
file_dir = 'E:/my_files'
file = File.open("E:/ids_to_remove.txt", "r")

file.each_line.map do |line| 
  id, file_name, group = line.split

  old_text = File.read("#{file_dir}/#{file_name}-details.txt")
  new_text = []

  old_text.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ /=/
      line_group, line_ids = line.split("=")

      if line_group.strip == group.strip
        line_ids = line_ids.split(",").reject { |l_id| l_id.strip == id }.join(",")
      end

      new_text << "#{line_group}=#{line_ids.chomp("\n")}"
    else
      new_text << line.chomp("\n")
    end

  end

  File.write("#{file_dir}/#{file_name}-details.txt", new_text.join("\n"))
end
```

I'm sure there is a better way to handle the extra `"\n"`, but this will get the desired output.

Comment: Just Brilliant, why haven't I thought like you :) Thanks a lot.